# How to style the placeholder text of an Ionic <ion-select> component?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4, shadow-dom

How to style the default/placeholder text of an `<ion-select>` component in the Ionic framework? The default text is inside the shadow root, so therefore the HTML element has a class of "select-placeholder" it cannot be accessed via traditional CSS.

[image]framework.com/docs/api/select#css-custom-properties

The docs for [ion-select](https://ionic) mention to use custom properties but there are only two custom properties:

```
--placeholder-color

--placeholder-opacity
```

Both work fine for updating the color and opacity, but I would really like to specifically update font-weight and font-style, and there aren't custom properties for those.

The [Ionic team mentions](https://ionicframework.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-ionic-and-why-its-awesome/#comment-4676023209) that if there are not custom properties, to "access the shadow root of the element and apply the styles yourself in JS." But they don't expand on how to do that.

How, specifically, can I add styles in the shadow root of Ionic components where a custom property is not supplied?

Comment: Can you give an id to your `ion-select` and check what `document.getElementById("the-id").shadowRoot.querySelector(".select-text").class` returns?

Comment: It returns 'undefined' but if I change "class" to "className" it returns the 2 classes that are on that element: "select-text select-placeholder"

Comment: So, based on your suggestion I tried this: document.getElementById("mySelectBoxThing").shadowRoot.querySelector(".select-text").style.color = "hotpink"

And that works. But wondering if there's a better approach.

Comment: I'm using Ionic4 for what its worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR; Add the part attribute to the placeholder element inside the shadow dom and then style using ::part(thePartName) in css.**

Here was my solution (I didn't love it). And by the way I am on Ionic 4.

So ultimately, the problem with styling elements inside the shadow DOM of certain ionic components, is that traditional CSS selectors from an outside* style stylesheet have zero affect on elements inside the shadow dom. This is one of the main points of the shadow DOM: to create encapsulated components where CSS doesn't leak in and doesn't leak out. There are two exceptions that I'm aware of:

1 - Use one of Ionic's [CSS variables (aka CSS Custom Properties)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#css-custom-properties). These are limited to `--placeholder-color` in Ionic 4 and [adding `--placeholder-opacity` in ionic 5](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17446). I happened to be on ionic 4 so i couldn't take advantage of the opacity variable. However to use these custom properties you would do so like this:

```
ion-select {
 --placeholder-color: 'hotpink';
}
```

I needed to style font-weight, font-style, and opacity so I needed another solution other than CSS Custom Properties.

2. There is a second way to style elements inside the shadow dom and that is using the `::part()` pseudo element.

html that lives in the shadow dom provided by Ionic:

```
<div part="SorryIonicDoesntAddThisAttribute" class="select-text select-placeholder>my text</div>
```

Your css:

```
::part(thePartName) {
  opacity: 1;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

If the "part" HTML attribute exists on the element inside the shadow dom its like a portal into the shadow dom.

However in Ionic 4, **Ionic doesn't add the part attribute to the ion-select component's elements** in the shadow dom.

I used javascript to add it (inspired by @ivanreutkers comment) to add the part attribute so I could thus style it in CSS.

```
document.getElementById("the-id").shadowRoot.querySelector(".select-placeholder").setAttribute("part", "myPartName");
```

*Outside, meaning the stylesheet for my website/application and not the specific styles provided by Ionic that live inside the web component.

Comment: Also - I was in Angular so I ended up creating an attribute directive that adds the part attribute to the shadow DOM inspired by this gist: https://gist.github.com/Sroose/3d8a25b469ecc4e556558d5caa986be1

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line in your app.scss file like this:

```
::ng-deep {
  .select-text {
    color: white;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but normal CSS selectors can't enter into the shadow root unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, Did you add !important? like this color: white !important;

Comment: It's not an issue of "css specificity" from what I can tell. It's more an issue that these iconic elements are in the shadow dom, and therefore they are protected from styling that comes from outside of the ionic web component.